# Python error when trying to use linux "mat" application

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am on Linux Mint 18.3 and I have installed the mat application ( Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit -- https://mat.boum.org/ ).

I always used it and it worked perfectly on other distros. Today when I installed on my Linux Mint, when I ran the command, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mat", line 10, in <module>
    from libmat import mat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libmat/mat.py", line 22, in <module>
    import strippers  # this is loaded here because we need LOGGING_LEVEL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libmat/strippers.py", line 9, in <module>
    import office
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libmat/office.py", line 15, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Poppler', '0.18')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 102, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Poppler not available
```

On their website, it says that it does not wok with Python 3. Is it maybe the cause of error? I don't understand about programming so much, so I'm not sure if this error is because of the Python version ot it's another different thing.

Comment: probably is the version, did you try wit 2.7?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I did not check it, I don't understand much about python etc, but tonight at home I'll check my python version and I'll update here